# Are any sites HTML5 or CSS W3C level 2.1 valid?

Tags: accessibility

I am reviewing an educational website and it does not pass HTML5 nor CSS w3.org acessibility tests. Is this the norm? Do any sites these days pass these tests?

Eg.

> Bad value Format for attribute name on element `meta`: Keyword format is not registered.
>
> & did not start a character reference. (`&` probably should have been escaped as `&amp;`.)
>
> Property `border-radius` doesn't exist in CSS level 2.1 but exists in [css3] : `10px` 
>   Unknown pseudo-element or pseudo-class `:nth-child`

Comment: To which "acessibility tests" are you referring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am reviewing an educational website and it does not pass HTML5 nor CSS w3.org acessibility tests. Is this the norm? Do any sites these days pass these tests?

The W3C validator was updated about two months ago to look at HTML5. There are some bugs, but I haven't been following the progress. The bugs are mainly around some ARIA-stuff. In general it is good to get the code as valid as possible. Note if the validator says it is 100% valid code, that doesn't mean the site is accessible, it isn't an accessibility tester. The same goes for the CSS test, it matches your CSS to the spec, and makes sure that youu have `:` and `;` in the right places. It may some color contrast tests, but I am not 100% on that. If the validator does, it uses WCAG 2.0 to check the ratios.

> Bad value Format for attribute name on element meta: Keyword format is not registered. & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &.)

This is an age old issue. Somewhere you have an `&`, maybe for a link, such as: `mysite.com/var1=Ryan&var2=B`. The validator thinks you are trying to say `&var2` is a valid HTML entity and saying that your link should be coded as `mysite.com/var1=Ryan&amp;var2=B`.

> Property border-radius doesn't exist in CSS level 2.1 but exists in [css3] : 10px Unknown pseudo-element or pseudo-class :nth-child

Either the CSS Validator is still checking against the CSS 2.1 Spec or it is saying "Hey not all browers understand CSS3 yet, so you may want to change it."